# img onload executes early

Tags: javascript, image, onload

i'm working on a system that loads, render, and refreshes images on a canvas
for my javascript engine project but when im using the img.onload it executes before i'm able to set the img source

the main function:

```
function addImgToList(canvas, url, sw, sh) {
    TempVar = {s: CheckSlots(canvas, 0)
              };
    that = this.TempVar;

    CurrentGFXElements[canvas].images[TempVar.s] = {
        img: new Image(),
        sw: sw,
        sh: sh,
        sprites: [],
        active: true,
        lx: 0, // last x
        ly: 0, // last y
        ew: 0,
        eh: 0,
        animations: 0
    };
    /*error calculations begins before img has been loaded
    */

    CurrentGFXElements[canvas].images[TempVar.s].img.onload = function (TempVar) {
        calcSprites(canvas, TempVar.s, sw, sh);
    } (TempVar);

    //CurrentGFXElements[canvas].images[TempVar.s].img.src = url;

    CurrentGFXElements[canvas].indexList[TempVar.s][0] = 1;
    return TempVar.s;}
```

note: i know that the line that sets the src is commented

the calculation function:

```
function calcSprites(canvas, slot, sw, sh, height) {
TempVar = {
    h: CurrentGFXElements[canvas].images[slot].img.height,
    w: CurrentGFXElements[canvas].images[slot].img.width,
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    s: slot
};

TempVar.columns = TempVar.w / sw;
TempVar.rows = TempVar.h / sh;
TempVar.sprites = TempVar.columns * TempVar.rows;

console.log(TempVar);

for (i = 0; i < TempVar.sprites; i++) {
    CurrentGFXElements[canvas].images[slot].sprites[i] = [[TempVar.x, TempVar.y]];
    console.log(CurrentGFXElements[canvas].images[slot].sprites[i]);

    TempVar.x += CurrentGFXElements[canvas].images[slot].sw;

    if (TempVar.x >= (CurrentGFXElements[canvas].images[slot].sw * TempVar.columns)) {
        TempVar.x = 0;
        TempVar.y += CurrentGFXElements[canvas].images[slot].sh;
    }
}

return TempVar;}
```

the full file can be viewed here:(this link isn't up 24/7)(skip the commented part of the code at the top)

http://preview.47chkdyfg0j54s4iwcuw0aw3py5e9udikcegdc7r578ehfr.box.codeanywhere.com:3000/engine/graphics.js

Comment: add your function in document ready and try.

Comment: why are you using `TempVar +=` when `TempVar` is an object?

Comment: @charlietfl it says TempVar.y += CurrentGFXElements[canvas].images[slot].sh which both are numbers

Comment: @stanze what do you mean?

Comment: @jonaskjellerup no, above the `if` ...  `TempVar += CurrentGFXElements[canvas].images[slot].sw;`

Comment: @charlietfl that has been corected now

Comment: doesn't `onload` fire when the element is loaded? I don't believe it has anything to do with when the image actually loads.

Comment: @ps2goat nope read this: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onload.asp

Comment: @jonaskjellerup, that's `XUL`, not `HTML`.

Comment: @ps2goat sorry wrong link it should be corrected now, but it's still at image load not element load

Comment: Is `TempVar` something I'm not aware of, or are you using it as a regular variable name?

Comment: @ps2goat TempVar is just a regular variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the error it seem's to be whenever you pass arguments to a anonymous function the function will automatically activate this will also happen if you assign a function to the onload:

```
//will activate instantly
img.onload = someFunction();

//same as above
img onload = function (argument) {//insert code}(argument_to_pass);

//these will work without problems
img.onload = someFunction; //this one should work but not 100% sure

img.onload = function () {//insert code}
```